# React validate input field using errors array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input

I'd like to apply a few validation rules to an HTML input field, and add the error message to the `errors` state array each time the check doesn't go through.

```html
<input
  name="email"
  type="email"
  value={ email }
  placeholder="Type your email address here..."
  onChange={ handleChange }
/>
<button
  className="Form_Submit"
  onClick={ handleSubmit }
>
  <i className="fas fa-arrow-right" />
</button>
```

```js
handleSubmit() {
  const {
    values: {
    email = '',
    errors = []
  } = {}
} = this.state;

if (!validateEmailAddress(email)) {
  errors.push('Please provide a valid e-mail address');
}

if (isEmpty(email)) {
  errors.push('Email address is required');
  }
}
```

### Updated:

```js
if (!validateEmailAddress(email)) {
  this.setState({
    errors: [...errors, 'Please provide a valid e-mail address']
  });
}

if (isEmpty(email)) {
  this.setState({
    errors: [...errors, 'Email address is required']
  });
}
```

The following syntax doesn't take the number of component update times, therefore I end up with 4-8 messages each time I click the submit button. Are there ways to handle the input field validation in the `errors` array (to display all messages in the end) to push just a single value to an array, and then remove it?

Comment: I will recommend [Yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) for errors handling.

Comment: Please do not suggest any side libraries, the question is about React and JavaScript. Lazy answers are bad :c

Comment: It's about approach, you are actually mutating your state without telling react. Which is the reason you are not getting an updated state.

Comment: Use `this.state` instead of `Array.push`

Comment: I have updated the code, can the updated solution somehow be adjusted?

Comment: It should work as expected but there is a chance to get duplicated strings. Try errors as an object which is easy and efficient too

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing setting state.

```
handleSubmit() {
  const {
    values: {
      email = '',
      errors = ''
    } = {}
  } = this.state;

  if (!validateEmailAddress(email) && !errors.contains('Please provide a valid e-mail address')) {
    errors.push('Please provide a valid e-mail address')
  }

  if (!!email && !errors.contains('Email address is required')) {
    errors.push('Email address is required');
  }

  setValues({...rest, errors});
  if (!errors.length) { 
    doFunc(); //your expected function
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code, can the updated solution somehow be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this code https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/push+unique+values+in+array+javascript

```
const myArray = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
const unique = [...new Set(myArray)]; // ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

Set in javascript stores unique values so it will be helpful. You can apply the below code

```
const errorSet = new Set([...this.state.errors]);
if (!validateEmailAddress(email)) {
  errorSet.add('Please provide a valid e-mail address');
}

if (isEmpty(email)) {
  errorSet.add('Email address is required');
}
this.setState({
   errors: [...errorSet]
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).